How to configure git push trigger in AWS codepipeline?
"Since there is no proper way to configure push filter using cdk for aws codepipeline, I've tried the below. But it gives me an error which is posted below. Tried multiple things but non of them worked. Anybody has a clue on this?
Code:
const cfnPipeline = pipeline.node.defaultChild as codepipeline.CfnPipeline;
cfnPipeline.addPropertyOverride("Triggers.0.GitConfiguration.Push.0.Branches", {
  Includes: ["main", "dev"],
});

Error:
Properties validation failed for resource PipelineABCD5664GGD with message: [#/Triggers/0/GitConfiguration/Push: expected type: JSONArray, found: JSONObject]


The closing " is missing after dev

Try cfnPipeline.addPropertyOverride('Triggers.0.GitConfiguration.Push.0.Branches.Includes', ['main','dev']).

tried but still the same

Seems like the Triggers.0.Gitconfiguration.Push array is missing - set the entire array instead of just the first element:
const cfnPipeline = pipeline.node.defaultChild as codepipeline.CfnPipeline;
cfnPipeline.addPropertyOverride("Triggers.0.GitConfiguration.Push", [
  { Branch: { Includes: ["main", "dev"] } },
]);


Tried but not worked

@ShanWave007 what's the error?
